# Restrict the null body from entering into a camel endpoint in xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, integration

```
<camel:route id="messageRoute">    
<camel:from ref="fromMessageQueue" />
<camel:processor ref="queueMessageProcessor" />
<camel:to ref="toMessageQueue" />
</camel:route>
```

In this code snippet, receiving a message from q queue then processing it in queue message processor, finally placing it into to message queue. While processing the message in processor, the body of exchange is getting set to null. I need to prevent the exchange with null body from entering into to message queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [simple language](https://camel.apache.org/simple.html) and [content based router](https://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html):

```
<camel:route id="messageRoute">    
    <camel:from ref="fromMessageQueue" />
    <camel:processor ref="queueMessageProcessor" />
    <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
            <camel:simple>${body} != null</camel:simple>
            <camel:to ref="toMessageQueue" />
        </camel:when>
    </camel:choice>
</camel:route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Exchange Pattern InOut i.e.

```
<blockquote>
  <camel:route id="messageRoute">    
  <camel:from ref="fromMessageQueue" />
  <camel:processor ref="queueMessageProcessor" />
  **<setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>**
  <camel:to ref="toMessageQueue" />
  </camel:route>
</blockquote>
```

Basically you are telling Camel to In the same message, modify it, and send(Out) back the modified message.

Comment: How Exchange pattern will solve this problem? If null  is getting set in the body of out-exchange, will that not enter into next endpoint ?

Comment: If you setting null in the out body that mean you want to pass that value in next endpoint. Will you explain the use case in more.

Comment: Creating an envelope in the processor and setting it into the body of exchange. Then passing this exchange to the next endpoint which is a message queue.  There is a scenario where the created envelope is null so resulting into a NPE due to null body in exchange. Need to prevent exchange with null body to enter into message queue.

Answer (score 1):

@Amit: This is what you can do to avoid NPE:
1. Set the header in your Camel Process based on the body value e.g.
Here I am setting the header IsNull based on the In body content.

```
public class QueueManagerProcessor implements Processor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        if(exchange.getIn().getBody()==null){
            exchange.getOut().setHeader("IsNull", "true");
        }else{
            exchange.getOut().setHeader("IsNull", "false");
        }
    }

}
```

2. In your Route Builder you can apply Content based Routing using choice and when condition

   ```
          <xpath>$IsNull = 'false'</xpath>
            <camel:to ref="toMessageQueue" />
   ```

Comment: Up-voting your answer, worked for me.  But @Husky227 solution looks cleaner.